# Spring Batch Reading Multiple files with Dynamic names

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am a newbie in Spring Batch. I have already created working code using FlatFileItemReader where I am getting the preset file name from a property file. In a new requirement I would not know the file name. For instance, the below could be the files and their names, all placed in the same location.

```
...\files2read\<SOME-RANDOM-ID>.<YYMMDD>.<EXTN>

...\files2read\123.140613.ABB - @Pick this
...\files2read\234.140610.ABB
...\files2read\345.140607.ABB

...\files2read\123.140613.ABC - @Pick this
...\files2read\234.140610.ABC
...\files2read\345.140607.ABC

...\files2read\123.140613.ABD - @Pick this
...\files2read\234.140610.ABD
...\files2read\345.140607.ABD
```

There might be multiple files as the time goes, but I need to pick the latest file looking at the date  on the file name, and per each file extension  (i.e., @Pick this)

I have looked at the MultiResourceItemReader where the resources can be specified as [pattern](http://books.google.com/books?id=1QGyKvGu1t4C&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194&dq=spring%20batch%20reading%20file%20pattern&source=bl&ots=TJVizD-wuz&sig=z9PXBlqgJsuLFDW-ifbMJAhtAMU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nTabU6SxD8X4oAT3o4HoDg&ved=0CG0Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=spring%20batch%20reading%20file%20pattern&f=false). This will allow me to read all the files matching a file extension but not as I require here. Is there an elegant solution to this, rather than writing each file type pattern as a separate step? Also I still not sure how to pick the latest file looking at the date here.

I am using this [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/iosample/multiResource.xml) as a reference. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can implements your own `ResourcePatternResolver` and return resources you want.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at the samples.